# Differentiable with f(x) and and g(x) using chain rule

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, chain-rule

I got this differentiable problem that I'm really stumped on.

*| `f(x)` is the red line and `g(x)` is the blue line with `f(x) ∗ g(x)` and `u(x) = f(x) g(x)`.*

So, I'm trying to find the values of `j'(-4)` and `u'(2)`. I know I need to find the slope which will be used in the chain rule of `f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) * g'(x)`.

I'm having trouble finding the slope of `f(x)` and `g(x)`.

Greatly appreciate some help!

[image: Image of graph]

Comment: Hint: $f$ is linear and $g$ is piecewise linear.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The function $f:\textbf{R}\to\textbf{R}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f(x) := \frac{2x}{3} + \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

The function $g:\textbf{R}\to[1/2,2]$ is given by
\begin{align*}
g(x) :=
\begin{cases}
1, & x\in(-\infty,-2],\\\\
\dfrac{x}{2} + 2, & x\in(-2,0],\\\\
-\dfrac{x}{2} + 2& x\in(0,3],\\\\
\dfrac{1}{2} & x\in(3,+\infty).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Now you can obtain the expression of $f(g(x))$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Im sorry, but I am so confused - how would I plug in the g(x) piecewise into u(x)?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you help me understand how f(x) and g(x) will go into u(x)?

Comment: @marksawnson Consider the expression of $g$ corresponding to each interval and compose it with the expression of $f$. If you are still having difficulties, tell me so that I can edit my answer. I am assuming you are interested in the formula for $f(g(x))$. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find j prime of (-4) and u prime of (2). 

So for j prime of (-4), I got the solution as just f(x). I found this because g(-4) is a negative and according to the piecewise function, all numbers between infinity and -2 is 1. 

As for u prime of (2), I got 4(x+1)/3(x-4) because g(2) is represented by (-x/2+2). Looking at the problem, I realized I don't need the chain rule.  Hopefully, I am right :)!